# C# Como enviar o valor do numericUpDown ao textBox em Hexadecimal?

Tags: c#, hexadecimal

então... o numericUpDown até tem o formato de contagem em Hexadecimal, porém ao enviar para o texBox ele contabiliza somente em decimal
tem alguma forma do textBox receber o valor dado do numeric em Hexadecimal?

Eu envio o valor do numeric ao textBox assim:

```
    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(numericUpDown1.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só você fazer um parse para inteiro e chamar o método `ToString` com a formatação `X2` para dois digitos em hexadecimal.

```
textBox1.Text = ((int)numericUpDown1.Value).ToString("X2");
```

Comment: Poxa valeu mito, saiu perfeito!

Comment: Tiago, sou ficou um problema, eu tanto tava enviando o valor do numeric para o textBox quanto do textBox para o numeric, como uma forma de Load, ao abrir o arquivo eles sincronizam e o úsuario pode ajustar o valor do textBox manualmente pelo numeric, tem como fazer o mesmo processo? ou dessa vez vou ter que abdicar dessa sincronizção?

Comment: numericUpDown1.Value =int.Parse(textoBox1.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)